std::fill can't work with associative containers, say std::map? Why?
There is such declaration for std::fill in cppreference:
template< class ForwardIt, class T >
void fill( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value );

But I can't figure out why it could not be use for std::map.Since the cppreference does not say it can't be applied to std::map, I am really concious why.Here is the demo code:
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
 
int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> v {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}};
 
    std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), {666, 666});
 
    for (auto pair : v)
        std::cout << "{" <<pair.first << pair.second << "}" << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

Here is what the compiler complains:
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:9:14: error: no matching function for call to 'fill(std::map<int, int>::iterator, std::map<int, int>::iterator, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
    9 |     std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), {666, 666});
      |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/13.1.0/algorithm:60,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1000:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _ForwardIterator, class _Tp> constexpr void std::fill(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&)'
 1000 |     fill(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, const _Tp& __value)
      |     ^~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:1000:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:9:14: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter '_Tp'
    9 |     std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), {666, 666});
      |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/13.1.0/algorithm:73:
/usr/local/include/c++/13.1.0/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:191:1: note: candidate: 'template<class _ExecutionPolicy, class _ForwardIterator, class _Tp> __pstl::__internal::__enable_if_execution_policy<_ExecutionPolicy, void> std::fill(_ExecutionPolicy&&, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&)'
  191 | fill(_ExecutionPolicy&& __exec, _ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, const _Tp& __value);
      | ^~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/13.1.0/pstl/glue_algorithm_defs.h:191:1: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:9:14: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 3 provided
    9 |     std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), {666, 666});
      |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Changing the key of an element in a map can actually changes the map internal structure (which is usually a balanced tree). It makes it problematic to do while iterating over it.

Keys in a map are constant, they can't be changed.

@Someprogrammerdude you are right. My mistake (although even if they were not contant I think it would have been problematic during an iteration because of what I wrote).

Not to mention that keys are supposed to be unique (atleast hashed to different values)

@AlexeyS.Larionov Hashing is normally done in the unordered containers, not std::map and std::set.

Stored element of data (node) of map is value_type. For map<Key,T>::value_type is std::pair<const Key,T> so you cannot change the Key in already existing node. You have to remove old elements and create new ones. fill does overwrite the existing ones; it's simply the wrong tool for the job because an associative container has to manage these tasks itself.
There is also a problem of invalidating iterators after each change. Although C++17  had added map::insert (which allows insert nodes)  and insert_or_assign and C++23 had added insert_range.
